# latex background image issue

Tags: background, latex

Using the Latex eso-pic package I am inserting a background image using the following lines:

```
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
 \AtStockLowerLeft{
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{picture}}}

\begin{document}
...
```

This works; every page now has my picture as the background. However, as soon as I insert a picture in any of my chapters and I open the created *.pdf document using adobe reader (after succesfull compilation using pdflatex), adobe crashes with the following message: "There was an error processing a page. There was a problem reading this document (131).". I use the following lines for inserting pictures:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
 \begin{centering}
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\columnwidth]{my_picture}
 \par\end{centering}
 \protect\caption{This is my picture.
 \label{fig:my_picture}}
\end{figure}
```

I have the feeling that this is caused by the fact that I'm trying to draw two pictures on top of each other (background + in-text picture). But I have no idea on how to solve this. Any ideas?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Orions; thanks for the pointer.